# Prevent Empty Elements in XML via XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

I'm working on an XSD file and when validating an XML file with it I want to restrict empty elements. Eg.,

`<myElement>this is not empty</myElement>`

would pass validation, however

`<myElement/>` or `<myElement></myElement>`

would not pass validation.

Thanks for any help you may offer!

ps.  I accidentally posted this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126546/prevent-empty-elements-in-xml-via-xsd under an unregistered account.  I apologize for any inconveniences.

UPDATE:
The element must be able to not exist in the XML at all, so I can not use minOccurs="1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<xs:simpleType name="myString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:minLength value="1"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="root" type="myString"></xs:element>
```

However that will still match on `<root> </root>` but you could use a regex restriction to change that if it is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `minOccurs="0"` to require the tag, then have a validation regex that checks for one or more characters.

Comment: The element must be able to not exist in the XML at all, so I can not use minOccurs="1".  Thanks for the help though!  I've updated the OP to reflect this.

Comment: See change - make it minOccurs='0' in that case.  The rest still applies.