# How can I parse an empty element with tinyxml2?

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

Using tinyXml2, I can parse

```
<MSG_TIME>2010-07-01 14:28:20</MSG_TIME>
```

just fine, but

```
<MSG_TIME></MSG_TIME>
```

and

```
<MSG_TIME/>
```

both throw exceptions in C++ when those are perfectly valid XML (to my knowledge). Does anyone have a fix or suggestion for this? I do not control the source of this XML, and I need to be error tolerant.

Comment: Does the xsd you're using prevent empty elements -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126646/prevent-empty-elements-in-xml-via-xsd?

Comment: Report the bug to the authors of the library (and, if you can, fix it yourself). Meanwhile I would go for a better XML parsing library, like pugixml (my favorite).

Answer (score 6):

This answer assumes you're trying to load valid XML with an empty element.

`XMLElement::GetText()` returns `nullptr` if the element is empty, so you can do a simple check like this:

```
std::string szData;

// Get the element
XMLElement pElement = xmlDoc.FirstChildElement("MyElement");

// Check whether the element contains data & if so, extract it as text
if (pElement->GetText() != nullptr) szData = poElement->GetText();
```

This question actually pointed out a bug with the [TinyXML2 tutorial](http://shilohjames.wordpress.com/tag/tinyxml2/) I wrote a few months ago, so thanks for posting it! :)