# XML Schema: How do I allow an element with attributes but no text?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to create an XSD for validating an XML file, and several elements need to have attributes but no text.

E.g. This should be considered valid:

```
<DEPRECATED value="blah"/>
```

These are invalid:

```
<DEPRECATED>blah</DEPRECATED>
<DEPRECATED value="blah">bad text</DEPRECATED>
```

I tried declaring a complex empty element as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_empty.asp), but either I'm interpreting the example incorrectly or the example itself is wrong (see error below):

```
<xs:element name="DEPRECATED" type="stringValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>

<xs:complexType name="stringValue">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Error: Complex Type Definition Representation Error for type 'stringValue'.  When  is used, the base type must be a complexType. 'integer' is a simpleType.

I also tried defining the complexType this way:

```
<xs:complexType name="stringValue">
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

But that considers the invalid examples above as valid. [EDIT: Correction, the above *does* work.]

I've also played around with the answers to similar questions ([Define an XML element that must be empty and has no attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751782/define-an-xml-element-that-must-be-empty-and-has-no-attributes), [Prevent Empty Elements in XML via XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126646/prevent-empty-elements-in-xml-via-xsd)) but no luck.

How do I validate that an element has attributes, but NO text?

Comment: Argh - the answer is in the question. The complexType defined above DOES work, there was a problem with my XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XML will be valid**

```
<DEPRECATED value="blah"/>
```

**and this XML**

```
<DEPRECATED>blah</DEPRECATED>
```

**and this XML**

```
<DEPRECATED value="blah">bad text</DEPRECATED>
```

**will be invalid using this XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="DEPRECATED">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="value"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Odd - when I try this, it still considers <DEPRECATED value="blah">bad text</DEPRECATED> as valid (I didn't try the other invalid case). Does it matter that the DEPRECATED element is itself in a sequence belonging to another complex type? Will add details to the original question...

Comment: No, that should not matter.  Please provide ***exact*** XSD and XML and error message if you're still having trouble, because being in a sequence, or being defined anonymously or explicitly should not matter.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem - the deprecated element in my file (the one I expected to be invalid) was the child of another element, not a "property" element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like this

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
    targetNamespace="stackoverflow" xmlns:tns="stackoverflow"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DEPRECATED" type="tns:deprecatedType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="deprecatedType">
        <xs:attribute name="number" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This XML document was valid

```
<sf:Test xmlns:sf="stackoverflow"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="stackoverflow test.xsd">
    <sf:DEPRECATED number="123"/>
</sf:Test>
```

This XML document was invalid

```
<sf:Test xmlns:sf="stackoverflow"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="stackoverflow test.xsd">
    <sf:DEPRECATED number="123">TEST</sf:DEPRECATED>
</sf:Test>
```

If you want to restrict the attribute you might need something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="deprecatedType">
    <xs:attribute name="number">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Sorry. did not mean to offend. The original question seemed to be trying to add a restriction to the attribute so was trying to show how that might be done and put the whole thing in full context.

Comment: looks like the original comment was deleted. hope the answer helps

Comment: BTW: I tested with your nested complexTypes and got it to work. How are you testing the validation?

Comment: You're right, it does work. The deprecated element in my file (the one I expected to be invalid) was the child of another element, not a "property" element. #facepalm
And I saw the comment you're referring to before it got deleted. Wasn't mine :). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="EmptyType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:length value="0" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:complexType name="DeprecatedType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="EmptyType">
        <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```